# How to convert PySpark DF of vectors to RDD?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe that contains vectors for one of columns ("features" column, the output of a Vector Assembler). I'm attempting to convert the DF to an RDD to perform map operations on the vector elements, but I keep getting errors while simply trying to convert to RDD.

My df looks like:

```
+---------+---------------+
|       id|       features|
+---------+---------------+
|103043842| (54,[0],[1.0])|
|103044195|(54,[42],[1.0])|
|103044272|(54,[24],[1.0])|
+---------+---------------+
```

Where the schema is:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```

Converting to RDD using:

`df.rdd`

The main error seems to be a numpy import error, but I definitely have it imported since I use the library elsewhere in my script.

```
ImportError: ('No module named numpy', <function _parse_datatype_json_string at 0x7fb3d66dcf50>,
```

The full Error stack is:

```
17/12/01 16:04:21 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 24.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/spark-playground.py", line 187, in <module>
    transformed_meta = transform_meta(meta_df)
  File "/home/hadoop/spark-playground.py", line 102, in transform_meta
    print(t.take(3))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1343, in take
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 992, in runJob
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 24.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 24.0 (TID 1242, ip-172-31-27-17.us-east-2.compute.internal, executor 6): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1339, in takeUpToNumLeft
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 144, in load_stream
    yield self._read_with_length(stream)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 169, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 454, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 894, in _parse_datatype_json_string
    return _parse_datatype_json_value(json.loads(json_string))
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 911, in _parse_datatype_json_value
    return _all_complex_types[tpe].fromJson(json_value)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 562, in fromJson
    return StructType([StructField.fromJson(f) for f in json["fields"]])
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 428, in fromJson
    _parse_datatype_json_value(json["type"]),
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 913, in _parse_datatype_json_value
    return UserDefinedType.fromJson(json_value)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 705, in fromJson
    m = __import__(pyModule, globals(), locals(), [pyClass])
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/param/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
ImportError: ('No module named numpy', <function _parse_datatype_json_string at 0x7fb3d66dcf50>, (u'{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"long","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"features","type":{"type":"udt","class":"org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT","pyClass":"pyspark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT","sqlType":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"type","type":"byte","nullable":false,"metadata":{}},{"name":"size","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"indices","type":{"type":"array","elementType":"integer","containsNull":false},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"values","type":{"type":"array","elementType":"double","containsNull":false},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}},"nullable":true,"metadata":{"ml_attr":{"attrs":{"binary":[{"idx":0,"name":"2802"},{"idx":1,"name":"521"},{"idx":2,"name":"2864"},{"idx":3,"name":"2770"},{"idx":4,"name":"3026"},{"idx":5,"name":"2744"},{"idx":6,"name":"3042"},{"idx":7,"name":"6769"},{"idx":8,"name":"3084"},{"idx":9,"name":"2742"},{"idx":10,"name":"7549"},{"idx":11,"name":"2986"},{"idx":12,"name":"3002"},{"idx":13,"name":"3082"},{"idx":14,"name":"2863"},{"idx":15,"name":"2562"},{"idx":16,"name":"137"},{"idx":17,"name":"2862"},{"idx":18,"name":"335486"},{"idx":19,"name":"2746"},{"idx":20,"name":"6771"},{"idx":21,"name":"6767"},{"idx":22,"name":"541"},{"idx":23,"name":"2987"},{"idx":24,"name":"2767"},{"idx":25,"name":"2745"},{"idx":26,"name":"6772"},{"idx":27,"name":"2985"},{"idx":28,"name":"26089"},{"idx":29,"name":"6349"},{"idx":30,"name":"964"},{"idx":31,"name":"136"},{"idx":32,"name":"2763"},{"idx":33,"name":"2747"},{"idx":34,"name":"2766"},{"idx":35,"name":"6351"},{"idx":36,"name":"2765"},{"idx":37,"name":"7554"},{"idx":38,"name":"3085"},{"idx":39,"name":"1382"},{"idx":40,"name":"3003"},{"idx":41,"name":"7553"},{"idx":42,"name":"2769"},{"idx":43,"name":"2762"},{"idx":44,"name":"7555"},{"idx":45,"name":"3023"},{"idx":46,"name":"6770"},{"idx":47,"name":"6350"},{"idx":48,"name":"2768"},{"idx":49,"name":"7551"},{"idx":50,"name":"2764"},{"idx":51,"name":"966"},{"idx":52,"name":"4822"},{"idx":53,"name":"__unknown"}]},"num_attrs":54}}}]}',))

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1690)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1678)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1677)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1677)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:855)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1905)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1849)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:671)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1339, in takeUpToNumLeft
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 144, in load_stream
    yield self._read_with_length(stream)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 169, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 454, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 894, in _parse_datatype_json_string
    return _parse_datatype_json_value(json.loads(json_string))
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 911, in _parse_datatype_json_value
    return _all_complex_types[tpe].fromJson(json_value)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 562, in fromJson
    return StructType([StructField.fromJson(f) for f in json["fields"]])
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 428, in fromJson
    _parse_datatype_json_value(json["type"]),
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 913, in _parse_datatype_json_value
    return UserDefinedType.fromJson(json_value)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 705, in fromJson
    m = __import__(pyModule, globals(), locals(), [pyClass])
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512140843138_0020/container_1512140843138_0020_01_000007/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/param/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
ImportError: ('No module named numpy', <function _parse_datatype_json_string at 0x7fb3d66dcf50>, (u'{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"long","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"features","type":{"type":"udt","class":"org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT","pyClass":"pyspark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT","sqlType":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"type","type":"byte","nullable":false,"metadata":{}},{"name":"size","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"indices","type":{"type":"array","elementType":"integer","containsNull":false},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"values","type":{"type":"array","elementType":"double","containsNull":false},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}},"nullable":true,"metadata":{"ml_attr":{"attrs":{"binary":[{"idx":0,"name":"2802"},{"idx":1,"name":"521"},{"idx":2,"name":"2864"},{"idx":3,"name":"2770"},{"idx":4,"name":"3026"},{"idx":5,"name":"2744"},{"idx":6,"name":"3042"},{"idx":7,"name":"6769"},{"idx":8,"name":"3084"},{"idx":9,"name":"2742"},{"idx":10,"name":"7549"},{"idx":11,"name":"2986"},{"idx":12,"name":"3002"},{"idx":13,"name":"3082"},{"idx":14,"name":"2863"},{"idx":15,"name":"2562"},{"idx":16,"name":"137"},{"idx":17,"name":"2862"},{"idx":18,"name":"335486"},{"idx":19,"name":"2746"},{"idx":20,"name":"6771"},{"idx":21,"name":"6767"},{"idx":22,"name":"541"},{"idx":23,"name":"2987"},{"idx":24,"name":"2767"},{"idx":25,"name":"2745"},{"idx":26,"name":"6772"},{"idx":27,"name":"2985"},{"idx":28,"name":"26089"},{"idx":29,"name":"6349"},{"idx":30,"name":"964"},{"idx":31,"name":"136"},{"idx":32,"name":"2763"},{"idx":33,"name":"2747"},{"idx":34,"name":"2766"},{"idx":35,"name":"6351"},{"idx":36,"name":"2765"},{"idx":37,"name":"7554"},{"idx":38,"name":"3085"},{"idx":39,"name":"1382"},{"idx":40,"name":"3003"},{"idx":41,"name":"7553"},{"idx":42,"name":"2769"},{"idx":43,"name":"2762"},{"idx":44,"name":"7555"},{"idx":45,"name":"3023"},{"idx":46,"name":"6770"},{"idx":47,"name":"6350"},{"idx":48,"name":"2768"},{"idx":49,"name":"7551"},{"idx":50,"name":"2764"},{"idx":51,"name":"966"},{"idx":52,"name":"4822"},{"idx":53,"name":"__unknown"}]},"num_attrs":54}}}]}',))

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Do you have numpy installed on your workers?

Comment: I figured this out - turns out numpy was not installed on all the workers. I'm using AWS EMR, and apparently my 'pip install numpy' command only installed on the master and not the workers. Solved this problem by including a boostrap action for my cluster to pip install numpy - this installed numpy on all workers.